# At third-level, are rangers allowed to select a drake as their animal companion?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, animal-companions, dragons

I wasn't able to find anything about this in 5th Edition. A drake seems that it would exceed the 1/4 challenge rating stated in the PHB.

In this specific campaign, our Dungeon Master allows anything that is accessible on D&D Beyond **not** including Homebrew content.

I did find the [Drake Warden Ranger archetype](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/ranger/archetypes/paizo-ranger-archetypes/drake-warden-ranger-archetype/), which I assume is for Pathfinder, and thought it might be possible that I’d overlooked a similar variant in D&D 5E.

Comment: If you plan was to have a Drake called 'Doctor' and that has been ruined, can I suggest instead a [Dog](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Mastiff#content) called 'Snoop'?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

### Not as an "animal companion," because Drakes aren't Beasts

[Drakes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=0&filter-search=drake&filter-cr-min=&filter-cr-max=&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-is-legendary=&filter-has-lair=), though animal like in appearance and behavior, have the creature type of dragon, not beast. And the Ranger's Companion states:

> Choose **a beast** that is no larger than Medium and that has a challenge rating of 1/4 or lower (PHB, p. 93 bold added).

"Beast" is not just a descriptive word here, it is a creature type (see Monster Manual page 6) that applies to some creatures and not others. If a creature is a beast, it will say so in its stat block (right under its name, right after its size).

There are some interesting examples of intimidating (read: awesome) creatures that are 1/4 CR beasts: a [pteranodon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=0&filter-search=pteranodon&filter-cr-min=&filter-cr-max=&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-is-legendary=&filter-has-lair=) springs to mind. But drakes are not beasts, so **they would not be eligible as a Beast Master Ranger's Companion** (even if a CR 1/4 one existed in some published adventure).

### The new Drakewarden ranger type will give you a Drake companion

As of October 2021 (almost exactly three years after this question was asked), a new Ranger subclass has been published (in the book Fizban's Treasury of Dragons) called the [Drakewarden](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#Drakewarden). This class grants the Ranger the ability to summon a Drake companion at 3rd level. The statistics for said drake can be found in source book mentioned above. This subclass is worth looking into if you are invested in a drake as your companion, since (as mentioned before) the Beastmaster Ranger cannot have drakes as their companions.

Answer (score 35):

The lowest-CR [drake on D&DBeyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters?filter-type=0&filter-search=drake&filter-cr-min=&filter-cr-max=&filter-armor-class-min=&filter-armor-class-max=&filter-average-hp-min=&filter-average-hp-max=&filter-is-legendary=&filter-has-lair=) has CR = ½

A [ranger's companion](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/ranger#BeastMaster) must have CR ≤ ¼.

So **no**, you cannot (currently) have a drake as your animal companion. To do so would require either a modification to the ranger rules or a new drake with CR ≤ ¼ (and the beast type, as [gandalfmeansme rightly points out](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/134699/23970)) to be published by WotC.